# How to convert feature_easting and feature_northing into longitude and latitude in R?

Tags: r, maps, coordinates

I have polygon data specified using latitude and longitude and point data in easting and northing. My question is how can I convert the easting and northing data to longitude and latitude points to plot over the polygons? My data is as follows:

```
  feature_easting feature_northing
             <dbl>            <dbl>
 1          209420           922820
 2          260123           666308
 3          337004           795573
 4          259210           723869
 5          105583           934443
 6          136664           645354
 7          224222           677810
 8          229931           682446
 9          426639           544285
10          271574           798532
```

My immediate thought is to use a simple formula to transform the data, but I also think that there is likely much more to it than this. Does R have a built-in function for this or perhaps a package that might help?

Comment: which country is you data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sp::spTransform`. I have assumed your initial dataset is epsg:27700 (British National Grid)

```
library(sp)
east_north <- SpatialPoints(dat,
                     proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))

spTransform(east_north, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```